# Timer overhead causing memory overflow

Tags: go, channel

From the timer.Stop() [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Stop)

> Stop prevents the Timer from firing. It returns true if the call
>   stops the timer, false if the timer has already expired or been
>   stopped. Stop does not close the channel, to prevent a read from the
>   channel succeeding incorrectly.

I need to find a way to destroy timer object or channel created in program via [After](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After) or [NewTimer](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTimer). I am not using these functions directly, just another library that implements timeout using these. The more requests I handle the program's memory keeps on increasing and then gets killed.

I have looked into the following places but without much help:

1. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/A597Btr_0P8
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/-xnFsH_ZRqU
3. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/rYthykbCLHk
4. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/hjioKxSJ3Tc

Please help, need to fix this desperately.

UPDATE

The suspected code is at https://github.com/gocql/gocql/blob/986e33a705412161497203d55d0669d04282f5ff/conn.go#L546

```
var timeoutCh <-chan time.Time
if c.timeout > 0 {
    timeoutCh = time.After(c.timeout)
}

select {
case err := <-call.resp:
    if err != nil {
        if !c.Closed() {
            // if the connection is closed then we cant release the stream,
            // this is because the request is still outstanding and we have
            // been handed another error from another stream which caused the
            // connection to close.
            c.releaseStream(stream)
        }
        return nil, err
    }
case <-timeoutCh:
    close(call.timeout)
    c.handleTimeout()
    return nil, ErrTimeoutNoResponse
case <-c.quit:
    return nil, ErrConnectionClosed
}
```

How do I know this ? I ran go tool pprof to capture memprof and what it showed is :

[image: section of memprof]

Comment: Can you provide the code that suffers from the problem?

Comment: So you're saying the references to these hundred of thousands of timer channels are not going out of scope, so they don't get garbage collected?

Comment: Hi all I have added the suspected code and pprof memprofile output to question.

Comment: That code isn't incorrect, you don't need to explicitly clean up a timer (`time.After` is just shorthand for `time.NewTimer(d).C`). How long is your timeout set for, and what is the request rate?

Comment: @JimB Timeout is set to 15 min and request rate is > 3K per second (as fast as it can take). I have tried replacing `time.After` with time.NewTimer and using Stop(). It is leaner but still runs out of memory after some time.

Comment: @user568109: timers can't be GC'd until they fire. At that rate you're trying to manage over 2700000 timers after the first 15min. Can you bring timeout value down to a few seconds, or don't use that timeout at all?

Comment: @JimB Let me try it and will let you know.

Comment: @JimB Process wasnt killed after I removed the timer. Since there is no option to disable timeout I had to patch the library. Now that timer did cause the issue, is this the expected usage ? because it still lingers even if the operation is completed. For a high frequency service this is not good. Large timeout is required as the query result can take time to complete fetching. There should be a better way.

Comment: @user568109 timeout can be disabled by setting it to 0 in the cluster config

Answer (score 2):

I've merged a fix for this, https://github.com/gocql/gocql/pull/661 please raise an issue if you run into further issues